# how to loop column/cell values in dataframe without loop?

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to pandas and I am having trouble accessing the value in the columns. It keeps returning index labels and so my function doesn't work. The examples I found uses condition but I don't need any condition, I just want this function to apply to all cells.

I am trying to find the equivalent to this

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
'#do something...row['arrival']
```

but using datframes:

```
def distance_lat_long (data):
    #lat/long 
    try:
        origin_lat = geolocator.geocode(data['arrival']).latitude
        origin_long = geolocator.geocode(data['arrival']).longitude
        des_lat = geolocator.geocode(data['destination']).latitude
        des_long = geolocator.geocode(data['destination']).longitude

        orig= (origin_lat, origin_long)
        destin= (des_lat, des_long)
        distance = vincenty(orig,destin).meters
        print (distance)
        return distance
    except:
        print ("Can't find location")
```

Comment: Use `apply` with the `axis=1` parameter.  With your function that would be `df.apply(distance_lat_long, axis=1)` or often we skip the `axis` and just do `df.apply(distance_lat_long, 1)`